# How do I get the host name of a server?

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client, host

I have created a server and client in C++ and I want them to connect to each other while they are on the same network, but running on different machines. I am currently using the following code to get the server to connect to the network:

```
#define HOST_PORT "27015"

WSADATA wsaData;
int status;
struct addrinfo * data;
struct addrinfo hints;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_IP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

char hostname[1024];
hostname[1023] = '\0';
gethostname(hostname, 1023);

if (getaddrinfo(hostname, HOST_PORT, &hints, &data))
{
    std::cout << "Unable to translate host name to address\n";
    WSACleanup();

    return 1;
}
```

The client attempts to connect using similar code:

```
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

struct addrinfo hints;

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

char hostname[1024];
hostname[1023] = '\0';
gethostname(hostname, 1023);

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
int iResult = getaddrinfo(hostname, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

if (iResult != 0)
{
    std::cout << ("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();

    return false;
}
```

This works fine when the client and server are on the same machine, but how do I allow them to connect when they are on separate machines? I expect that I need the client to connect to the same host name when using `gettaddrinfo()`, but how do I get the host name of the server? (e.g. If `hostname` on the server becomes "InsertNameHere", how do I allow the client to detect "InsertNameHere" and use it as the first parameter in `getaddrinfo()`?)

Comment: A client _must_ know the server's hostname or IP.

Comment: @CristiFati Then how can I make the client and server connect while they're on different machines?

Comment: The server is ok. For the client, instead of calling `gethostname`, you should specify it (or read it from a config if you will).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is fairly common, and there’re several approaches to this.

**Manual Configuration**

For example, your server might find out it’s IP4 address, print it to the console, then you somehow manually specify that address in your client app, e.g. as a command-line parameter, or in some configuration file.

This is the most developer-friendly, and least user-friendly, way.

**Service Publishing**

Your server may register itself on startup to some place from where the clients may read. People usually implement this method in enterprise Windows environments, where the Active Directory is that “some place”. If this is your case, [see this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740536(v=vs.85).aspx) for the WinSock APIs you need.

**Service Discovery**

Or, you may implement a discovery mechanism yourself, for example using UDP broadcasts.

In your server, listens on some UDP port, wait for some discover datagram, and respond with some “discovered OK” datagram.

In your client, on startup, send a discover UDP datagram to the broadcast address to that UDP port number. If there’re your server[s] running on the same subnets where the client is, the client will receive the “discovered OK” message[s]. If there’s just one response, you know there’s a single accessible server, and you can connect right away. If there’re several responses, it could mean there’re multiple servers, you can ask user where to connect.

This approach is relatively hard to implement correctly (e.g. UDP offers no guaranteed delivery so retries and timeouts are needed), however it’s the most user friendly way. If you ever played old LAN games like Quake, that’s how they discover their servers.

I'd like to add there're third-party libraries that you could use, such as [Collage](http://www.libcollage.net/) and [ReplicaNet](http://www.replicanet.com/), however I don’t have a hands-on experience with those, can’t recommend any of them.

Comment: I'll probably take the first option then, but how would I go about accomplishing it? The server will be used on multiple machines. On the current machine I'm using to make the server, the IP4 address might be `X`, but I'll then put it on another machine once it's working which might have an address of `Y`. How would I be able to get the specific address of the machine that the server is on at any time and then transfer it to the client so that it can connect to the server?

Comment: Would I be able to let the client just search for the name of the server on the network (it's executable name is "MusicServer.exe") and connect to it after finding it? If so, how do I do it? Would I still use `getaddrinfo()` in the server and client so that they can connect to each other?

Comment: No, MusicServer.exe is the process name on your PC. Process names aren’t exposed to the network.
You may certainly use names instead if IP, but not the name of the process, but network name of the server computer.
To find out the name of a computer, run command prompt (Windows+R, cmd, enter), then in the command prompt type hostname and press enter.

Comment: In your code, you have a call to gethostname that gets the name of the local computer. You need to remove this call, and instead of the “hostname” buffer use a command-line argument, or a configuration parameter, that will receive the server’s host name. Then proceed to getaddrinfo().

BTW for testing and debugging, when both server and client are on the same PC, you may use a special host name called “localhost” that will always connect you to the local PC.

Comment: Any particular command-line argument that I can use to find the server's name? I'm very much new to running servers and clients on different machines (as in this is the first time I've done it).

Comment: Well, I think you probably should start with the following sample depending on your platform:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889(v=vs.85).aspx – Windows
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm – Linux
They both implement roughly the same, a very simple TCP client and server.

Comment: I've looked at the MSDN link (I'm using Windows) and it doesn't seem to have helped. If I run the client and server on two different machines on the same network using the code on the MSDN page, they both look for a connection but don't find one. (I will mention now, one machine is a laptop using WiFi and the other is a desktop PC wired to a router)

Comment: On the PC where you run server, run windows command prompt, type hostname, press enter. This command will print the network name of the server. Then start server.exe from the sample. On another pc, where you run the client.exe, add the network name of the server as a command-line argument when starting the client, e.g. run “client.exe Ben-PC”.

Comment: If this won’t work: (1) Ensure they both connected to the same router (2) Turn off firewalls on both PCs and retry, by default, Windows has the built-in one called “Windows Firewall”, or you might have some other one like zone alarm or outpost (3) In some routers, there’s a security feature called “Wireless isolation” where router blocks network traffic between wireless LAN and wired LAN, while allowing them both to access the internets, ensure this settings is off

Comment: And one more thing. While the firewalls are switched off on your 2 PCs, you should be able to ping them from one another. On each computer, in the command prompt, type "ping -4 Ben-PC" and on another one "ping -4 Ben-Laptop" (I don’t know the names of your 2 PCs and I assumed they’re Ben-PC/Ben-Laptop), and it should print something like "Reply from 192.168.1.247: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64". If ping doesn’t work, it could mean something’s wrong with your network. Could be router hardware, router software, router configuration, PCs configuration, etc.

Comment: Okay then. Even though the client and server will be run on different machines, they will be used by the same person. So the server would print the name of its host and then the user would input the host name to the client's console so that it could use the input in the `getaddrinfo()` call?

Comment: Yep.
You can find out the name of the current PC with hostname command.
Or if you want your app to print it, call gethostname() API, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To connect to remote server you need to obtain it's IP address or hostname. The default approach is either to manually pass it as a parameter or to use naming services like ZooKeeper (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service))

The easiest and best way is to configure your network and use DNS instead of direct IPs (for example myserver1.mycompany.com:27015 where 27015 is a TCP port).

Comment: The name of the server executable is "MusicServer.exe", so would I use `getaddrinfo(MusicServer:27015, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result)` in the client?

Comment: IP address/host name has nothing with 'executable name'. That is how networks work. When you type in your browser 'www.google.com' - you are doing absolutely the same. You are providing SERVER address manually. There is no any way of client to know where to connect 'automatically'. You have to provide your client with IP/hostname manually. Through command line arguments for example: 
    myapp.exe server.address.here
Or you can use some 'discovery service', but i think that is not your case.